# Static fields in Android

Tags: java, android, static

I am newbie in android and java development and i want to understand some things.

1. Is it bad practice to use static field for transfer data between
   activities and fragments? For me, it is much easier than using
   extras in intents.
2. Why many programs use context as parameter in constructors and methods when we
   can    use static field to one point access for application context?
   For    example:

   ```
   public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {
   public static volatile Context context;
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           context = getApplicationContext();
       }
   }
   ```

So can someone explain, in which cases should use static fields in android (i mean for classes such as adapters, lists, context, etc)? And when using non-static fields, getters/setters, extra in intents is better way then static fields?

Comment: Because global state is pure evil. In fact, if you google that phrase, the first link gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to use static field for transfer data between activities and fragments?

Generally speaking, yes. There are certainly Android patterns for using static data members, but for "transfer data", they are rarely used, for all the classic reasons why global variables are considered to be poor form in most programming languages.

The primary exception is when the activities are in the same app *and* the data to be passed is either too big to go in an extra or is of a data type that cannot go in an extra. Even then, you are better off with a more flexible approach (e.g., have a static singleton manager of some object cache, where you have the shared data, where you use extras for passing IDs or keys around for accessing the cache).

> For me, it is much easier than using extras in intents.

You do not use extras to communicate from an activity to a fragment, or vice versa. At most, you use extras as part of passing data between activities.

Beyond that, too many inexperienced developers value today's pain over "the sum of all tomorrow's pain". In other words, the use of global variables has been demonstrated time and again to reduce maintainability of a program over time. You may not care right now. Your co-workers care. Your boss cares. The future you will care, when you try to maintain the code that you are writing today.

> when we can use static field to one point access for application context?

Among other reasons, frequently that is the wrong `Context` to use. Only use the `Application` instance when you know **precisely *why*** using the `Application` instance is the right `Context` for the circumstance. For example, creating UIs from `Application` (e.g., via `LayoutInflater`) frequently gives you the wrong results.

[This epic blog post by Dave Smith](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) helps outline the roles of the different types of `Context`.

> in which cases should use static fields in android

Avoid them where possible. Use them sparingly where needed. Bear in mind that your process can be terminated at any point when your app is not in the foreground, and so static data members need to be a cache for data stored in a persistent fashion, if you don't want to lose that data.

> i mean for classes such as adapters, lists, context, etc

Assuming that by "lists" you mean `ListView`, using static data members is inappropriate for any of those cases, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Is it bad practice...

Yes. `Activity` and `Fragment` are transient objects.  They come and go on demand.  In the case of an `Activity`, it is created automatically by the framework when needed.  Your app can have multiple instances of the same `Activity` class created simultaneously, depending on how you have designed your app and the state of the user's task/back stack.  In these cases, `static` tracking of a single `Context` would break things in the app.

> 2. Why many programs use context...

This is because of the nature of the `Context` object.  It is one of the most confusing things in Android.  Not all `Context` objects are created equal.  The `Context` returned from `getApplicationContext()` is a singleton for your application; but, each `Activity` and `Service` instance is a separate instance of `Context` and is transient (see above).  For a great explanation, see this great article from Dave Smith: http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: Note also that you should NEVER try to access something in an activity from another activity and making something static in an activity risks big memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

@google,

> 1. Static variable shows you unexpected behavior.Some times it's free the memory allocation and some time not. So its not reliable while
>      extras store the variable in bundle, So its reliable.
>
>    2. Because Context is "BaseClass" of Activity

And Very important Read this [useful guideline](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal) for use of static and getter/setter.

If any issue let me know.